# Get User Info From Google plus using jquery

Tags: asp.net, google-plus

I have do the application for get the values for the google plus. 
When get the user profile from Google plus got the error "Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Not Found [404]" on ASP.net

Sample code:

```
        string ProfileID = "45354354543543543543543"; 

        string GoogleKey = "XXXXXX";         
        var service = new PlusService();
        service.Key = GoogleKey;
        var profile = service.People.Get(ProfileID).Fetch();

        // Profile Name
        DisplayName.Text = profile.DisplayName;
```

I Got the error on "service.People.Get(ProfileID).Fetch();" time. But some profile ids are working fine and some will through error.

Comment: please provide your methid or code u r using

Comment: Are the ones that fail actually valid profile IDs?